Don't see TelemetryProcessor being hit but still see logs in application insight
I see lots of dependencies and other logs being logged in application insights, I want to filter lot of them cause they are filling up the app insights, but when try to filter them in TelemetryProcessor, not all of them come through TelemetryProcessor hence cannot really filter them.
I am not really sure the source of those logs.
Anyone has faced issue like this?
My TelemetryProcessor looks like this:
    public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        return;
    }

With the above code ideally, it should not log anything in application insight from code but I still see many logs.
Should be able to apply filter on all logs to application insights using TelemetryProcessor.

Please share the screenshot of your logs.

Please share more details ..program.cs and configuration file.

I created an ASP.NET Core WebAPI application and successfully prevented the logs from being logged in my application insights.
In your case, the issue might be that Application Insights SDK supports multiple telemetry processors. If there are other processors (like built-in ones for sampling or dependency tracking) in your project, they may be processing telemetry before it reaches your custom processor.

Make sure no other processor or initializer modifies the telemetry data before it reaches your custom processor. Ensure your custom processor is the first one to handle telemetry.

Sometimes, Application Insights may include platform or internal logs that your custom processor can’t filter. Check if the logs are platform-related, as these might bypass the custom processor.

You can filter the specific events if you want to, please refer this doc1 ,  doc2 for better understanding about the filter application insight events.

I've added the below line in my program.cs file, this will register the telemetry processor and ensures that the processor is used to filter out telemetry.


builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyTelemetryProcessor>();

Complete program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"]);

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyTelemetryProcessor>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I can successfully prevent the logs from being logged in my application insights.


Sirra, thanks for adding very detailed answer here, the problem with my code was that I was using UseAzureMonitor as
services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor();
This was not allowing me to control all logs through processor.
The moment I used only services.AddOpenTelemetry();, then I could control all the logs through processor.

Is your issue resolved?

Yes, with the changes above I have mentioned, my issue is resolved.
